# Passing a string from Python to Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, python-2.7

I'm trying to pass a string from Python to Javascript via ajax POST request but i'm finding serious difficulties.

I've tried both with and without using JSON.

Here's the code

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$.ajax({
    url: url, #url of the python server and file
    type: "POST",
    data: {'data1': "hey"},
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(" response ----> "+JSON.parse(response));
        console.log(" response no JSON ---> " +response);
    },
    error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {
        console.log("errmsg");
    }
});
```

**Python**

```
import json
print "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *";
if form.getvalue("data1") == "hey":
      out = {'key': 'value', 'key2': 4}
      print json.dumps(out)
```

Result is a empty JSON. when i do something like JSON.parse in javascript I get a unexpected end of input error, and when i try to get the length of the response data the size I get is 0.
I suppose that there should be some problems with the client server communication (I use a CGIHTTPServer) or maybe something wrong with the datatype that python or javascript expects.

I also tried without JSON, with something like
Python

```
 print "heyyyyy"
```

Javascript

```
 alert(response) //case of success
```

but I also got an empty string.

Could you please give me some advices for handling this problem ? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You shouldn't be using print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem using the method HTTPResponse from the Django Framework.

Now it's something very similar to this

PYTHON (answering the client with a JSON)

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
...
data = {} 
data['key1'] = 'value1' 
data['key2'] = 'value2' 
.....
response = HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type = "application/json")      
print response;
```

JAVASCRIPT (Retireving and reading JSON)

```
success(response) 
     alert(JSON.stringify(response));
```

Or if I just want to send a String or an integer without JSON

PYTHON (no JSON)

```
response = HttpResponse("ayyyyy", content_type="text/plain")
print response
```

JAVASCRIPT (Retrieving String or value)

```
success: function (response) {
    alert(response);
```

This works very good, and it's very readable and simple in my opinion!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to compare the two snippets of code [CGIHTTPRequestHandler run php or python script in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333632/cgihttprequesthandler-run-php-or-python-script-in-python) and http://uthcode.blogspot.com/2009/03/simple-cgihttpserver-and-client-in.html.

There isn't enough code to tell where your request handling code is but if it's in a class inheriting from `CGIHTTPRequestHandler` then you need to use `self.wfile.write(json.dumps(out))`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `print json.dumps(out)` you should use `return json.dumps(out)`

The `print` will only display it in python's console, just as `console` in javascript.

Comment: `json.dumps(out)` only converts out to a string, nothing else. It does indeed seem like print is the way to go http://uthcode.blogspot.com/2009/03/simple-cgihttpserver-and-client-in.html

Comment: Sorry. Should've `return`